# Протоидеология ― слитно или через дефис?

Tags: орфография, слитно-дефис

**Протоидеология** ― слитно или через дефис?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Прото-(от греч. protos, "первый")   префиксоид, часть сложного слова, указывающая на первичность, зачаточность данного явления как истока, начала, предвестия, например, в таких словах, как "прототип", "протозвезда", "прото-Ренессанс".

Другие учёные называют эту морфему приставкой. В любом случае протоидеология пишется слитно.

http://scibook.net/filosofiya-nauki-knigi/gnostitsizm-kak-protoideologiya-30397.html

Comment: HTTPS://PROJECTIVE_PHILOSOPHY.ACADEMIC.RU/83/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE- 
HTTP://POISKSLOV.COM/WORD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE

Comment: А почему на этой ссылке пишется "Прото-глобальная" (через дефис) и т. п.?

Comment: Людмила, посмотрите: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81. Неужели тут орфографическая ошибка?

Comment: Нет, не ошибка, это слово ещё не вошло в словарь, а раньше была тенденция писать имена собственные, названия с иноязычными частями через дефис. Я взяла определение из более раннего словаря, потом все слова с прото- привели к слитному написанию. Протоглобальная - тоже сейчас пишется слитно, а когда слово было неологизмом, в написании был разнобой, неизменяемые иноязычные части слов часто писали через дефис. Сейчас многие из них вошли в орфографический словарь, все пишутся слитно.

Answer (score 3):

Слитно.
Прото.. . (от греч. protos — первый) , часть сложных слов, указывающая на первичность, первооснову или предшествующий этап развития чего-либо (например, протоплазма, прототип) или на высшую степень (преимущественно в церковных званиях) , например протоиерей.
Во всех случаях пишется слитно.